# Update testing no-iCloud to iCloud support, get error 'no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement'

Tags: ios, testing, icloud, entitlements

I **only** have this issue when downloading my live app from the app store, then running my latest build over it via XCode. When I run the app 'clean' it works fine.

I want to make sure users will be able to update the app and have iCloud work as expected.

`NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: com.xxx.xxx has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement`

Will this be an issue when I submit the update or is my update testing flawed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing updates using OTA instead of directly through XCode, it appears to work fine. Not sure why, but the development profile isn't playing nice with the App Store profile, whereas the Ad Hoc profile is.